# How to make a condition true in a class?

Tags: php, html, mage

```
<?php $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); // get current url 
<?php $url = $category->getURL(); ?> 
<li class="<?php if ($currentUrl == $url) {echo 'active';} else{echo '';} ?> dropdown megamenu-fw "></li>
```

I'm trying to make a condition in li tag on class if the current url equal to current li url then add the class active but it is not working.

Comment: _but it is not working._ What does that mean? What errors do you see?

Comment: the above condition is not working that's my mean

Comment: it is not adding the class by this code

Comment: First of all there is a missing closing ?> tag in the first line. Second, you should make your first two lines look like: `<?php $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); // get current url 
$url = $category->getURL(); ?>` . Third, I would do a `var_dump($currentUrl.'--------'.$url);die;` to check what is inside the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

If below code not working then you can check first variable value of `$currentUrl` and  `$url`.

```
<?php $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); // get current url 
<?php $url = $category->getURL(); ?>
<?php if ($currentUrl == $url) {echo '<li class="active dropdown megamenu-fw "></li>';} else { echo '<li class="dropdown megamenu-fw"></li>';} ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is the URL right? Can the if-statement be true?
may you can try to get the URL other way:

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

By the way (may not the real problem):
Your line 1 will send error: You open php in line 1 `<?php` but didnt closed it, than in line 2 you open php again line2: `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: yes the url is correct i did echo that which print the correct url

Comment: yeah sorry for that i forgot to close the php here  but i closed in my file

Comment: So there is no problem, i think. You tried to show all errors? `error_reporting(-1);`